# Find and clean-up unconfirmed customer accounts?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, backend, customer-account, register, confirmation

Is there a way to find and list the customer accounts in Magento's backend (or programatically) which have not been confirmed?

I would like to run this check and cleanup periodically as it often happens people make typos in their email address and register twice and one of the accounts is never used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a test.php file in your root folder of magento, then put the following code and run it, it will delete all the unconfirmed customers in magento.

```
  <?php 
ini_set("display_errors", true);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
umask(0);   
   $result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('notnull' => true));
   foreach($result as $res){
 try{
     Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res->getId())->delete();
     Mage::log($res->getEmail(). " DELETED",null, 'unconfirmed_delete.log');
 }catch(Exception $e){
      Mage::log($e->getMessage() ,null, 'unconfirmed_delete.log');
}
  }
```

You can see the deleted customer emails in unconfirmed_delete.log file in var/log folder.

cheers

***UPDATE:***

To view it in backend, you need to do some changes in

```
  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

If you are not familiar with block override, you can just copy it to local in following path and do your changes there.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

As it is a core file, you need to override it on local folder.

**Step :1 (Update the _prepareCollection method):**

Add below code at the bottom.

```
->joinField('confirmation',
            'customer_entity_varchar',
            'attribute_id',
            'entity_id=entity_id',
            "{{table}}.attribute_id='16'",'left');
```

The new _prepareCollection method will be like:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('confirmation')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')

        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
       ->joinField('confirmation',
            'customer_entity_varchar',
            'attribute_id',
            'entity_id=entity_id',
            "{{table}}.attribute_id='16'",'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Here 16 is the id of confirmation attribute. Means is 'attribute_id' from `eav_attribute` table where `attribute_code` is equal "confirmation".

**Step:2 (add a column in customer grid)**

Add below code

```
 $this->addColumn('confirmation', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Confirmation'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'confirmation'
 ));
```

before below code in `_prepareColumns()` method.

```
 $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                    'field'     => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

It will add a new column of "Confirmation" in admin manage customer grid. If it looks **blank**, that means the customer is verified.

Comment: Thanks. That might work (not tested yet) but I would like to be able to review before deleting. Is it possible to somehow add a column in the admin interface to show if the account is confirmed?

Comment: Please check my updated response.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The column gets added to the grid but the whole table becomes empty (no customers shown at all). No errors in log too. It seems to me there might be some error in the join statement but I don't know what it might be. BTW there is some function `getIsConfirmedStatus()` in /Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php. Is it possible to use it somehow instead of risking a wrong attribute_id (e.g. if this local code gets applied on another Magento site)? Unfortunately I don't know how to do it properly, I hope you can help.

Comment: Please use this query to get the attribute_id and replace it with 16  in prepareCollection method. `SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'confirmation'`

Comment: I understand the SQL query, it is 16 here too. But the grid gets empty after applying your code change: https://goo.gl/A6CCV2

Comment: Ok, here is what I found: 1) If I add 'left' to the joinField function parameters (i.e. make the join left) - the customer list shows but the confirmation column is empty; 2) in customer_entity_varchar there is no record with entity_id=16 which means the SQL logic is not correct and that's why there is nothing in the column. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Update (after more testing): So it seems the solution works in reverse to what you explained. If the account is not confirmed - a random string shows in the Confirmation column provided a 'left' join is used. I will edit your answer to clarify that and mark it as accepted. Let me know if anything needs to be added. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the left join will be also fine. I tested this on Magento enterprise 1.14.2, and it worked, I think your answer is correct. But I'll also check it again and update here :)

Comment: I have updated it. For confirmed users it will be blank. Thanks.